# jQuery File Upload Plugin single-file-uploads removed cancel button option

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

Hi I'm working with [JQuery File Upload plugin](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/).

It works well and I already implemented some functionality with it. However, I required uploading all files in bulk. This can be achieved setting the option:`singleFileUploads: false`

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
  // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
  //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
  autoUpload: false,
  singleFileUploads: false,
  //sequentialUploads: true,
  previewMaxWidth: 160
  });
```

However, if you activate that option the cancel button for each file disappear. For instance: 
with singleFileUploads: true
[image]
with singleFileUploads: false
[image]

I understand the logic behind disable the cancel button if asynchronous uploads are disabled.

But, I need to modify the control to still show the cancel button. I upload multiple files following several steps that require the bulk upload synchronous. The button cancel can help the user to organize and correct errors in the files required. Can anyone help me telling me, how can I modify the control to achieve this.

I think I have to modify the `jquery.fileupload.js` library. Unfortunately, I'm lost there.

I want to clarify something. I need to receive all the files in the same call. I have a method upload that collects them before verified.
[image]

So, the change suggested by Kumar does not help me.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below script:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload('option', {
            maxChunkSize: 10000,
            resizeMaxWidth: 1920,
            resizeMaxHeight: 1200,
            maxNumberOfFiles: 1,
            limitConcurrentUploads: 1,
            sequentialUploads: true,
            singleFileUploads:true
        });
```

> **Updated Below:**

You also have add button in HTML like below

```
<span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                    <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Add files...</span>
                    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
                </span>
```

Only Update `input`

**From**

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
```

**To**

```
<input type="file" name="files">
```

Just remove `[]` and `multiple` it will disallow you to select multiple files from choose file window and this will definitely work.

Hope it helps you

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution does not help me. I need to receive the entire set of files in the call. But, I want to give the user the option to add or remove files before the initial upload.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I added more information to the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, what you suggest it's not what I need to do. I need to keep the multiple selections of files as originally. But, I want to keep the multiple actions for remove possible items before the upload. The file-upload control by default changes the behaviour, and remove the possibility to modify the list of the objects as you select 'with singleFileUploads: false '.So, when you remove one object all the objects are removed automatically. What I need to change that behaviour with singleFileUploads: false. I know is a hack, I do not know how to achieve it. Anyway, Thanks for you help.

Comment: This answer is not completely accurate with what I need. However, it points to some interesting issues. In my case, I finished hiding the action column of the control. And then changing the behaviour of the buttons in the top panel. I give up trying to modify the source code of the control, due to its complexity and possible side effects.